# Set Image array in recyclerview from json data in android

Tags: android, json, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In my app I have got some json data from url. I have deserialize those data in controller class. Now I want to show those image into recyclerview.This recyclerview will be shown in detail activity. I have devided the relative layout into two part. First half is for information and the second half is for a recyclerview. I tried with the follwing code. The problem is I am very new in android developing and I am not getting the correct logic of doing this. I have explained in detail below-

Here is my model class

```
public class NewsModel {

@Expose
private String id;

@Expose
private String title;

@Expose
private List<AppImage> appImages;


public List<AppImage> getAppImages() {
    return appImages;
}

public void setAppImages(List<AppImage> appImages) {
    this.appImages = appImages;
 }

}
```

The AppImageClass is

```
public class AppImage {
    @Expose
    private String _id;

    @Expose
    private String alt;

    @Expose
    private String src;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getAlt() {
        return alt;
    }

    public void setAlt(String alt) {
        this.alt = alt;
    }

    public String getSrc() {
        return src;
    }

    public void setSrc(String src) {
        this.src = src;
    }
}
```

The adapter class is

```
public class NewsImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsImageAdapter.ImageHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<NewsModel> imageObject;

public NewsImageAdapter(Context context, List<NewsModel> imageObject) {
    this.context = context;
    this.imageObject = imageObject;
}

@Override
public ImageHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.newsdetail_image_row,parent,false);
    return new ImageHolder(view);
}

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(ImageHolder holder, int position) {
    final NewsModel currentImage=imageObject.get(position);

    for (int i = 0; i < currentImage.getAppImages().size() ; i++)
    {
        AppImage appImage = currentImage.getAppImages().get(i);
        Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(appImage.getSrc()).into( holder.images[i] ); }
         Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext());

   }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imageObject.size();
}

public class ImageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView images;

    public ImageHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        images= itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
      }
   }
 }
```

In Deatil activity

```
public class DetailNews extends AppCompatActivity { 
private List<NewsModel> newsObject;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_detail);
     setUpUIViews();
    //newsObject=getAllImageList();
 }

 private void setUpUIViews() {

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.image_list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DetailNews.this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new NewsImageAdapter(this,newsObject );
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
    private List<NewsImageModel> getAllImageList() {

    //how to set image here?


    return  images;

}
```

The json data looks like this

```
  [ 

  { "id": "5925280ec925a9a6dd5173bb",
  "title": "Headline",

    "appImages": [
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "source1",
        "_id": "12213"
      },
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "source2",
        "_id": "fdgdg"
      },
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "source3",
        "_id": "fdfdfdf"
      },
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "source4",
        "_id": "599d9018daf57d002c100ffa"
      },
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "source5",
        "_id": "f7879"
      }
    ],
   },
   { "id": "5925280ec925a9a6dd5173bb",
  "title": "Headline",

    "appImages": [
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "source1",
        "_id": "12213"
      },
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "source2",
        "_id": "fdgdg"
      },
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "source3",
        "_id": "fdfdfdf"
      },
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "source4",
        "_id": "599d9018daf57d002c100ffa"
      },
      {
        "alt": "",
        "src": "source5",
        "_id": "f7879"
      }
    ],
   },
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one "raw/item" for each image. You don't need use "Picasso" to load the images, you can use something like:

In your **RecyclerView.Adapter**

```
.
.
.

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderCustom viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.setImage("imageUrl");
}


static class ViewHolderCustom extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private final ImageView imageViewPhotoUrl;

    ViewHolderCustom(View v) {
        super(v);
        imageViewPhotoUrl = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo_url);
    }

     void setImage(String photo) {
        if (photo != null && !photo.isEmpty())
            new DownloadImageTask(imageViewPhotoUrl)
                    .execute(photo);
    }
}
.
.
.
```

Your **DownloadImageTask**:

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urlDisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null)
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to use piccaso how can I implement that. my main cofution in this line currentImage.getAppImages() . after getAppImages() i find nothing. I want to get src from AppImage Class.

Comment: I'm see in this web (http://square.github.io/picasso/) that you can use:

    Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(view);

Comment: But Iam not able to get the "src" in this line Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(currentImage.getAppImages().add(  ) )).into( holder.images ). how can I redirect to src

Comment: @tamrezh21 , you need **one ImageView** for **each AppImage** that you get from **currentImage.getAppImages()**

Comment: Some like:


`for (int i = 0; i < currentImage.getAppImages().size() < i++){
 AppImage appImage = currentImage.getAppImages().get(i);
 Picasso.with(holder.itemView.getContext()).load(appImage.getSrc())).into( holder.images[i] );
}`

Comment: Could you plese explain based on my code. I am still very new in android. Could you plaese wrote your code as answer form

Comment: If I use recyclerview why I need to loop throuh the image?

Comment: Your RecyclerView has one ImageView, so you can only set one src

Comment: holder.images[i] this line is showing error. Array type expected :found android .widget Image view. I have updated my question code. could you please have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152663/discussion-between-nico-t-and-tamrezh21).